# Show that $\int_{C}xyzds=\frac{\sqrt3}{32}R^4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that $$\int_{C}xyzds=\frac{\sqrt3}{32}R^4$$
where $C$ is the quarter circle of the circle $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2,x^2+y^2=\frac{R^2}{4}$  in the first quadrant.
My attempt:
$$x=\frac{R}{2}cos\theta,y=\frac{R}{2}sin\theta$$
$$\int_{C}xyzds=\int_{C}xy\sqrt{R^2-(x^2+y^2)}ds $$ and $ds=\frac{R}{2}$
$$\frac{\sqrt3R^4}{32}\int_{C}2cos\theta sin\theta d\theta$$ where $0\le\theta\le\pi/2$

On evaluating the integral I'm getting $\frac{\sqrt3R^4}{16}$
I can't figure out if its a calculation mistake on my part or typo in the book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\quad\displaystyle\int_C2\cos\theta\sin\theta\;\mathrm d\theta$
$\displaystyle=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin2\theta\;\mathrm d\theta$
$\displaystyle=\left[-\frac12\cos2\theta\right]_0^{\pi/2}$
$\displaystyle=\frac12-\left(-\frac12\right)$
$=1$

Comment: Oops..that was such a silly mistake!Thanks,anyways

Comment: You are very welcome =)